# xp_logininfo not getting latest permissions

Tags: c#, sql, .net, t-sql, windows-authentication

My website uses Windows Impersonation to impersonate a user's AD account, then it accesses the database and uses xp_logininfo to check which AD groups the user belongs to.

When I add or remove a user from a group, xp_logininfo doesn't recognize the changes until the dayafter.

I removed myself from a group, and then logged off my local machine, logged back on and checked my permissions via xp_logininfo. I still had access to the group I had been removed from.

Then logged off my local PC and all the remote desktops I was logged into, then re-logged in and viola, xp_logininfo  shows I no longer belong to that group.

I know users have to log off and back on again to get a new token that includes their groups and privileges. But I don't know why I have to log out of all remote desktops and PC's to get this new token.

Is there a way I can force a user's AD groups to refresh?

Are AccessToken's shared among all machines an AD account is logged into/impersonations?

Comment: Added WA since really the question will be answered by those experts quicker

Comment: I've discovered that when u sing sp_who2, only once my connection to SQL Server has expired does the AD AccessToken reset. Does SQL Server cache AccessTokens?